# Create a Map of SortedMap from a Map using lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a Map having entries as below

```
[{a.p=aa}, {a.r=aaaa}, {a.q=aaa}, {a.s=aaaaa}, {b.p=bb}, 
 {b.r=bbbb}, {c.r=cccc}, {c.q=ccc}, {d.s=ddddd}, {d.p=ddd}]
```

I want 'map of sortedmap' as below using lambda expression

```
[{a=[{a.p=aa}, {a.q=aaa}, {a.r=aaaa}, {a.s=aaaaa}]},
 {b=[{b.p=bb}, {b.r=bbbb}]},
 {c=[{c.q=ccc}, {c.r=cccc}]},
 {d=[{d.p=aaaaa}, {d.s=ddddd}]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Supplier<SortedMap<String, String>> supplier = new Supplier<SortedMap<String, String>>() {

        @Override
        public SortedMap<String, String> get() {
            return new TreeMap<String, String>((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
        }
    };

    // [{a.p=aa}, {a.r=aaaa}, {a.q=aaa}, {a.s=aaaaa}, {b.p=bb}, {b.r=bbbb}, {c.r=cccc}, {c.q=ccc}, {d.s=ddddd}, {d.p=ddd}]
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("a.p", "aa");
    map.put("a.r", "aaaa");
    map.put("a.q", "aaa");
    map.put("a.s", "aaaaa");
    map.put("b.p", "bb");
    map.put("b.r", "bbbb");
    map.put("c.r", "cccc");
    map.put("c.q", "ccc");
    map.put("d.s", "ddddd");
    map.put("d.p", "aaaa");

    Map<String, SortedMap<String, String>> collect = map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy((k -> k.getKey().substring(0, k.getKey().indexOf('.'))),
                            Collectors.toMap(k -> ((Entry<String, String>) k).getKey(), k -> ((Entry<String, String>) k).getValue(), (a, b) -> a, supplier)));
```

Comment: Why not using lambda instead of Supplier anonymous class? Also what's the point of specifying the comparator here? Why not just using `TreeMap::new`?

Comment: You don't need the cast here `(Entry<String, String>) k`. And you can use a method reference also: `Map.Entry::getKey` - `Map.Entry::getValue`.

Comment: Putting suppilier here to say that if we need to have a complex comparison we can use it e.g. if we have a key a.p.1, a.p.4, a.p.2, b.p.2, b.p.20, b.p.1.  Here in this example if sorting needs to done on numeric part then default comparator is not going to work, it needs to write some logic sort the keys based on numaric value in keys.  Yes if TreeMap's default constructor is to used, you are right you can use in the you have mentioned.  Thanks!